# PSQL row update using NEW statment

Tags: sql, database, plpgsql, postgresql

since it is possible to do: INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (NEW.*) in pl/pgsql
can we do something similar but for UPDATE clause using NEW ? I mean i want to
update some row using values from NEW object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to do what you haved mentiened.please refer to the following link:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html